Ubuntu 24.04 Camera don't found
tengo un computador acer aspire A315 recientemente he instalado ubuntu 24 lts en una particion como segundo sistema, y todo funciona correctamente excepto la camara, para esto ya he mirado dando los permisos necesarios, instalando controladores o otras aplicaciones de camara y tampoco la camara es una integrada con el portatil este viene por defecto con windows 11.

https://community.acer.com/en/discussion/690736/acer-aspire-3-a315-59-laptop-camera-not-working-fedora-38

use the link to find the solution to your problem.

The language of choice here at Ask Ubuntu is English. Please edit your question and translate it into English.
